# Unresolved supertypes for AppMeasurementReceiver

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase analytics and Firebase BOM. I need to create `AppMeasurementReceiver` programatically, becasue I have more than one receiver that needs INSTALL_REFERRER. Unfortunately I get an error that class that is implemented by AppMeasurementReceiver is missing. Missing class is com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzff$zza. It's hard to debug and guess what is missing.

```
class InstallRefererReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    private val otherReceivers = listOf(       
            AppMeasurementReceiver()
    )

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {   
        otherReceivers.forEach {
            it.onReceive(context, intent)
        }
    }
}

<receiver
    android:name="co.app.referer.InstallRefererReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD" />
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I get following error:

```
e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver, unresolved supertypes: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzff$zza
```

I can find undefined field in play-services-measurement. This undefinedtype type is probably the same type that `AppMeasurementReceiver` is implementing.

```
public final class zzff {
    private final <undefinedtype> zza;
```

**EDIT**
I found really ugly solution, just create AppMeasurementReceiver via reflection.

```
class InstallRefererReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    private val otherReceivers = listOf(        
            FixedAppMeasurementReceiver()
    )

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        otherReceivers.forEach {
            it.onReceive(context, intent)
        }
    }

    private class FixedAppMeasurementReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

        private val appMeasurementReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = try {
            Class.forName("com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver")
                    .newInstance() as BroadcastReceiver?
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            null
        }

        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            try {
                appMeasurementReceiver?.onReceive(context, intent)
            } catch (t: Throwable) {
                doNothing()
            }
        }
    }
}
```